# Automatically sound recording and stop when user stop speaking using audio recoder

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-audiorecord

I want to recode the voice when certain level of sound receive and stop audio recorder does not receive sound.

I am initially using Media recorder to check maximum amplitude when I get it then I start recording via audio recorder but I am unable to stop it because audio recorder have not any method to get max amplitude.

Comment: You mean like Talking Tom Application ?

Comment: Yes similar to talking tom App.

Answer (score -1):

You should try some thing like this:

```
readAudio = audioRecorder.read(data16bit, 0, buffer);
double fN = (double)readAudio;

double accum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < readAudio; i ++)
{
   accum += Math.abs((double)data16bit[i]);
}

double soundLevel = accum/fN;
```

Then check the value of soundLevel to see when the app should stop recording.

Comment: The issue with this is you're stuck to hand-engineered constant (something like `soundLevel < 5`). Is there a way to make this work in noisy environments as well?